# How do you draw and fill a parallelogram in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I've looked around a little, and I was surprised that I couldn't find a way to draw and fill a parallelogram with java swing. Is there a easy way to do that?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You can draw 4 lines that surrounds a parallelogram. As this is not a particular complicated task, I doubt if any UI framework will provide such.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, but I was looking for a way to fill a parallelogram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All (or at least most) drawing in swing is done by subclassing `JPanel` and overriding the `paintComponent` method. So it will start like this:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //Drawing stuff....
    }
}
```

From here, you're going to want to create a Parallelogram `Shape`, and fill it. The simplest implementation of `Shape` for your use is `Path2D`.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{

    private Path2D.Double parallelogram;

    public MyPanel(){
        parallelogram = new Path2D.Double();
        parallelogram.moveTo(0,0);
        parallelogram.lineTo(50,0);
        parallelogram.lineTo(100,50);
        parallelogram.lineTo(50,50);
        parallelogram.closePath();

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fill(parallelogram);
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of this panel and add it to a `JFrame`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.add(new MyPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g);`!

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Create a Shape using a Path2D object,
- start your parallelogram using its `moveTo(...)` method
- Continue drawing lines using its `lineTo(...)` methods.
- Draw in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method override of a JPanel.
- In this method cast the Graphics object into a Graphics2D object.
- Then call `fill(yourShape)` passing in your Path2D object.